# Redirect URL with Trailing Slash `/` to the one without in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, trailing-slash

When a URL is typed with a slash at the end it returns 404 not found page.
For example: `http://www.example.com/index/` gives 404 not found.
what code to add in .htaccess to redirect it?
For directories, it works fine but for html files it doesnt.
**NOTE:** I have included a code in .htaccess to remove file extensions so `index.html` becomes `html` and so on.

Comment: NOTE: Now you must also add this code in the question!

Comment: @Croises the code to hide file extensions is not relevant to the question. I have said that to make it clear that `index` in the example provided is a file and not a directory "folder".

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply remove all trailing slashes from your URLs using:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Just make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.

Comment: will this be applied to directories like `/images'? which I don't want.

Comment: It will be, but you can stop that form happening by using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images`